# Beta Regression in R - Coefficient Interpretation

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients, beta-distribution

I'm running a beta regression in R using the "log-log" link function, and I'm wondering what is the best way to interpret the output coefficients?

Can I use the "emtrends" function in the "emmeans" package to back-transform the coefficients such that the coefficients could be interpreted as "for every one unit increase in x, we would expect the response to increase/decrease by x?"

Comment: You don't back-transform the coefficients because they are not all on the same scale. Back-transform the predictions instead, e.g. emmeans(). Use emtrends() only when you have a covariate interacting with another predictor. See the vignette on transformations.